# On iOS, can you use your UINavigationController's UIToolbar as an input accessory view?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, inputaccessoryview

When my textfield becomes first responder, I'd like to change the items in the toolbar that is managed by `UINavigationController` and have it slide up above the keyboard as an `inputAccessoryView`, but I get this crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot choose layout method for
UIToolbar managed by a UINavigationController'
```

Must I create a separate UIToolbar for the `inputAccessoryView` is there no way to change the items and use it for both purposes? (I can see the logic in having a separate toolbar for a separate job, but I can also see the logic in not creating an unnecessary toolbar.)

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this same issue, and hoping for a soon answer.

Comment: Same here. Did anyone find a solution to this issue?